# change direction navmesh agent on collision encounter

Tags: navmesh

I have one player and many enemies. The enemies are following my player through the navigation mesh. Sometimes enemies get stuck because there is another enemy in-front of them. You can say both are in line.

Is it possible that when one enemy collides with other enemy in-front of it to change direction so that it avoids colliding with one another?

Comment: Yes? Have you tried? Did it not work? It's not very clear what you're asking here. Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 2):

This is an AI problem typically found in RTS games. Many of such games have solved the problem via different methods.

I personally like [this](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131720/coordinated_unit_movement.php?page=7) article and the [implementation](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131721/implementing_coordinated_movement.php) follow-up article as an introduction into advanced pathfinding.

So, the answer is definitely a **yes**. Off the top of my head you could try some of the following:

- Check for local enemy collisions and repath one of the unit
- Check for local enemy collisions and move aside the unit that's blocking the way
- Implement a flow-field pathfinding algorithm (used by Supreme Commander 2), ([theory](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/AIIDE/2008/AIIDE08-031.pdf), [more practical paper](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/crowd-flows/continuum-crowds.pdf))
- Implement a flocking algorithm like [BOIDS](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/) which is pretty intuitive